# Insert message into a process running in gwt-console-server from external application?

Tags: drools, jbpm, drools-flow

I'm a jBPM noob running jBPM5.4 in AS7.  I have tried posting this question on the jBPM duscussion board, but no luck, so I thought I'd try here on stack.

My Goal: Create the process in guvnor, run it in gwt-console-server, have my java application feed information to the process, and follow the current state in the jbpm Console.

So far, I have installed the jbpm console and console server as well as Guvnor and designer on jBOSS AS7.  I am able to create a process in Guvnor and run and monitor that process from the jbpm Console.  The missing piece is that I do not understand how to *externally* insert messages to the process that is running.

Using eclipse and the jBPM example, I can run a process and insert messages, but my goal is to use the jbpm console to monitor the processes.

I assume I need to access the knowledgesession running in the gwt-console-server, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Is it safe to access/modify a session that is persisted out to a database (ie, both gwt-console-server and my custom app would be able to modify it) and then the jbpm console would read from it?

I see in the BPM Console reference (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/BPMConsoleReference) that there is an Integration Layer, but there is nothing about how to leverage that - and the like in the doc is broken :(

Can someone point me to an example of an external application feeding messages to a jbpm process that is being monitored by jbpm-console or suggest ways to accomplish this?

Thanks very much for any insight.
-J

PS. I have the new jBPM Developer's Guide, but can't find anything in it to help me with this (so if I am missing something, I can handle a reference back to that guide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the console is just using the logs, so as long as you log to the same DB the console is using (with JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger) everything pretty much automagically works.  You can use either JBPMHelper.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(kbase) or JBPMHelper.loadStatefulKnowledgeSession(kbase, sessionId) depending on if you want to use the knowledge session started from the Console.  Also, if you borrow the Console's session, don't dispose it of course.

I read somewhere that you can give the session a business id (and soon do the same from your own code so that they automatically use the same session), but currently when I want to borrow the Console's session I use a kludge that just assumes the highest session is the one I want (it will be as long as the console is already running).

Answer (score 1):

The jBPM console has a REST api that exposes a subset of the functionality.  For example, if you model this feeding of information as the start of a process, or the sending of a signal, you could use the signal REST method to send this information to the console for processing.

It's also fine to use an external ksession to update a process instance.  As long as they are using the same database to store the information, everything should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Kris. Unfortunately, I'm not sure I understand your first point.  The REST interface to which you refer is the gwt-console-server?  I don't see a way to insert a signal event; am I missing that?

More specifically though, I have an Apache Camel app that currently routes messages it receives to the drools integration server.  Depending on the event, I would like to similarly route the message to an instance of jbpm.  It looks like my process will have catching intermediate events and and gates everywhere, but basically, I want the messages sent (and data therein) to drive the process.